# How to resolve "error sending: timeout expired while executing transaction" in hyperledger fabric?

Tags: node.js, timeout, hyperledger, chaincode

I'm trying to upload a bulk data. Im splitting the records like 100 & trying to invoke . The thing is first 100 transactions executing well after that Im facing an issue like below.

```
 DLT Error { Error: failed to execute transaction 53842934bed9ad4b1f604bdc253f2e06f5677383c0c91cc20f313fa40a85ebf8: error sending: timeout expired while executing transaction
at self._endorserClient.processProposal (/home/user/Project/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Peer.js:140:36)
at Object.onReceiveStatus (/home/user/Project/node_modules/fabric-client/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:1207:9)
at InterceptingListener._callNext (/home/user/Project/node_modules/fabric-client/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:568:42)
at InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (/home/user/Project/node_modules/fabric-client/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:618:8)
at callback (/home/user/Project/node_modules/fabric-client/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:845:24)
status: 500,
payload: <Buffer >,
peer: 
 { url: 'grpcs://ip:7051',
  name: 'ip:7051',
 options: 
  { 'grpc.max_receive_message_length': -1,
    'grpc.max_send_message_length': -1,
    'grpc.keepalive_time_ms': 120000,
    'grpc.http2.min_time_between_pings_ms': 120000,
    'grpc.keepalive_timeout_ms': 20000,
    'grpc.http2.max_pings_without_data': 0,
    'grpc.keepalive_permit_without_calls': 1,
    'grpc.ssl_target_name_override': 'peer0.tata.com',
    'grpc.default_authority': 'peer0.tata.com' } },
    isProposalResponse: true }
```

I have tried reducing 100 to 50 Records at a time & also increased the timeout in invoking file

```
 let handle = setTimeout(() => {
            event_hub.unregisterTxEvent(transaction_id_string);
            event_hub.disconnect();
            resolve({event_status : 'TIMEOUT'}); 
        }, 70000);
```

But still facing the same issue. Can anybody please help me to fix this Issue?